# Dataframe CSV files and output statistics

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this ( input1.csv file ):

1;16;15363;623

2;46;1001;209

3;79;74241;372

4;91;68063;105

5;57;56049;86

6;82;42348;272

I have this file in a folder, and i would like to make a new file in the same folder with some statistics about my input file(above) for ex. output1:
In this output file will be: sum of rows, min, max and average number etc.Is it possible to make it with pandas module?

Thank you.

Comment: `df.describe()` will give you the basic information. Use `sum() mean() min() max()` and then specify the axis. You need to be more specific as to what you are looking for.

Comment: when i run a program i would like to automaticaly recognize a csv input file which is already in the folder and write new one(output) with this statistics.